# Run time repositioning angular components views

Tags: angular

I wanted to reposition the components runtime and reload the page,
do i need to create components dynamically to achieve below

From:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <NG6componet1 ></NG6componet1>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <NG6componet2 ></NG6componet2>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <NG6componet3 ></NG6componet3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <NG6componet1 ></NG6componet1>
    </div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">
      <NG6componet3 ></NG6componet3>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <NG6componet2 ></NG6componet2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

how can i achieve this in angular 6

Comment: If these are the only components that are going to be swapped, then you can simply add those component tag twice and activate accordingly with `ngIf`. If the view is changing a lot, then its better to dynamically insert the tags into the dom.

Comment: thanks Amit, how should i dynamically insert, do u have any link which will help.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-a-component-in-angular